# Regex: select a string which does not have a group value at certain place

Tags: c#, regex

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I've got an input text, which looks something like this:

```
object("a").style.display="none";
object("b").style.display="none";
object("c").style.display="none";
object("d").style.display="none";
object("e").style.display="none";
object("g").style.display="block";
object("h").style.display="none";
```

I want to select all lines, where the .style.display!="none" (In this case, object("g").style.display="block";). I don't know in advance what the other value can be.

What is the best way to do this using regex?

Comment: Is this in a C# program? Then do you really need to use regexes?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Linq & Regex

```
var arr = Regex.Matches(myregexstr, @"(object\(""\w+""\)\.style\.display\=)""(\w+)""")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Where(m => m.Groups[2].Value != "none")
            .Select(m=>m.Groups[0].Value)
            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [regex negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Python example (sorry, don't have a C# available now):

```
import re

text = """
any text
another text
object("a").style.display="none";
object("b").style.display="none";
object("c").style.display="none";
object("d").style.display="none";
object("e").style.display="none";
object("g").style.display="block";
object("h").style.display="none";
"""

pattern = r"^object\(\"\w+\"\)\.style\.display\=\"(?!none).*?\";$"

for i in re.findall(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE):
    print i

# >> object("g").style.display="block";
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a pattern like this?

`object\("[^"]+"\)\.style\.display\="none";(\r\n)?`

*C# Unit test:*

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    string input = @"object(""a"").style.display=""none"";
object(""b"").style.display=""none"";
object(""c"").style.display=""none"";
object(""d"").style.display=""none"";
object(""e"").style.display=""none"";
object(""g"").style.display=""block"";
object(""h"").style.display=""none"";";

    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"object\(""[^""]+""\)\.style\.display\=""none"";(\r\n)?");

    string expected = "object(\"g\").style.display=\"block\";\r\n";

    string actual = pattern.Replace(input, string.Empty);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```